# I can't center my actors with ExtendViewport, Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, viewport

I'm making a level select screen and I need use ExtendViewPort (I can't use Fit for other reasons), but this viewport moves my actors to the left, I need center them. I put X and Y position corresponding with my virtual screen size. This is my problem:

[image]

I do this things:

```
setViewport(new ExtendViewport(720, 1280));

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    levelsStage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
}

actor.setPosition(10,100); (Examples..)
```

Sry for my bad english, I speak spanish.

Comment: can you provide more code?, do `setViewport()` is being called from a `Stage` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved my problem using this:

```
viewport.getWorldWidth()
```

I can't explain more because my english is so bad